# equivalent to the find coreutil command in python 3 for recursively returning all files and folders in a directory structure?

Tags: python, unix, python-3.x

What is best alternative to find in python (3) for recursively returning all files and folders in a directory structure?

I want something similar to:

```
find ~/x/y/ > ~/matches.txt
```

I rewrote a tip from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27457665/908494) and got something that kind of works, but it has some problems:

```
matches = glob.glob("/Users/x/y/*/*)
```

This will not work if there are any files in "~/x/y/" which could happen I'm also not sure it's a robust or idiomatic way to do this.

So what's the best way to copy the above find command in Python?

Comment: Note that `glob` _does_ actually work recursively, as you can see from [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/glob.py#l22). However, this isn't documented; you really should rely on `os.walk` (and `fnmatch`, if appropriate, as in your previous question) here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

To get directory, file name list:

```
import os

matches = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~/x/y')):
    matches.extend(os.path.join(dirpath, x) for x in dirnames + filenames)
```

To write the file list to text file:

```
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser('~/matches.txt'), 'w') as f:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~/x/y')):
        for x in dirnames + filenames:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(os.path.join(dirpath, x)))
```

[`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) is used to replace `~` with home directory path.

---

Alternative using [`pathlib.Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) which available since Python 3.4:

```
import os
import pathlib

matches = list(map(str, pathlib.Path(os.path.expanduser('~/x/y')).rglob('*')))
```

---

```
import os
import pathlib

with open(os.path.expanduser('~/matches.txt'), 'w') as f:
    for path in pathlib.Path(os.path.expanduser('~/x/y')).rglob('*'):
        f.write('{}\n'.format(path))
```

Comment: Alternatively, in 3.4... `for fname in pathlib.Path(os.path.expanduser('~/x/y')).rglob('*'):`...

Comment: @JonClements, Thank you for letting me know that. I updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Note that many of the "primaries" (aka filters) that `find` supplies require calling `os.stat` on every file (or the equivalent in `pathlib`), but (as you know from your previous question) `fnmatch` handles the `-name`/`-iname` primary. I believe there's a howto that you can google for showing how to map different primaries to Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda like os.dirwalk, but with new pathlib constructs:

```
import pathlib
def pathlibs_dirwalk(dir_path):
     dir_path = Path(dir_path)
     return { f.relative_to(dir_path) for f in dir_path.rglob('*') }
```

This one also chops off the root, so it's like like GNU find's version:

`find /usr/local/gdb-8.2a -printf '%P\n'`

`lib/libopcodes.a
lib/libinproctrace.so
bin
bin/gdb
bin/gcore`

Comment: Please put an actual path in your code. I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I like globs, since your question specifically says python 3, I'm more than happy to recommend using `os.scandir` + `yield from` to simplify the approach.

```
import os

def find(path):
    yield path
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for i in os.scandir(path):
            yield from find(i.path)

for i in find('.'):
    print(i)
```